# pyminizip causing a "version `GLIBC_2.33' not found"

Tags: python, gitlab, importerror

This issue just arose a few days ago and trying to figure out what happened.

Running a pipeline through gitlab and the test cases are failing from the test cases that import the library "pyminizip" This library is installed just like every other library in our requirements.txt file. This is the error that pops up:

> import pyminizip
>
> ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by
> /builds/company/server/repo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyminizip.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

I have no clue why this library is causing this error in my repo and it's failing our pipeline at the moment. Any ideas why this is happening?